# VB Scripting - comparing time values, one coming from a text file?

Tags: date, time, vbscript

I'm attempting to pull some information out of text file that is updated after I query a piece of equipment. The text file contains lines such as shown here (abbreviated):

```
05-Nov-13  11:11:54.3496 ( -1 7020 10244) scpeng.exe:Automation Server...
05-Nov-13  14:10:54.3496 ( -1 7020 10244) scpeng.exe:Automation Server...
05-Nov-13  14:10:54.3496 ( -1 7020 10244) scpeng.exe:Automation Server...
05-Nov-13  14:10:56.3496 ( -1 7020 10244) scpeng.exe:CServer.cpp,....
```

The text file can contain up to several weeks of information. I have a subroutine that will run a few seconds after I query the equipment which should allow for the reply and the applicable line to be present in the text file. In the routine, I am trying to scroll through the lines examining the date to arrive at the date of the subroutine call followed by the time (or a time ~10 seconds prior the the current time) to arrive at the lines pertinent to where the information could be found.

```
do
msg = msgstream.ReadLine
logdate = mide(msg,1,9)
logday = Cdate(logdate)
loop while logday < date

do
msg = msgstream.Readline
logtime = mid(msg,12,8)
'logtime = CDate(logtime) This mod is not working
loop while logtime < time
```

The date loop appears to work however the time is giving me problems. It does not error out but I can't get it to run beyond one line of text. Can anyone suggest a fix or better option? I have read that the built-in Date function can include the time but I do not believe this version I'm using does. Also, the text file contains times in a 24 hour format where I believe the time function returns values in a 12 hr format ie "12:43:27 PM ST".

Comment: Are you sure that `logtime < time` is true at the time you are running the script?

Comment: Well that's a good question. The logtimes that are less than the time of when I call the routine are the ones I want to ignore. When the logtime is greater than the routine call time, I want to start searching those lines using additional criteria.

Answer (score 2):

You're making this way too complicated. Simply parse the whole date string into a datetime value:

```
refdate = Now
Do
  msg = msgstream.ReadLine
  logdate = CDate(Mid(msg, 1, 19))
Loop While logdate < refdate
```

You can extract date and time portions from the value later, e.g. like this:

```
WScript.Echo DateValue(logdate)
WScript.Echo TimeValue(logdate)
```

Also, `Time` returns the current (unformatted) system time. Whether it's displayed in 12 hour or 24 hour format depends on your system's region settings. However, you can always get the hour (0-23) by using the `Hour` function.

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot, thanks. I'm still getting familiar with scripting in general.

Answer (score 0):

Parse each line with a regex to get the correct date and time part. I prefer a regexp above string manipulation functions because you can separate format and code.

Reassemble the date from the two parts and see if the date is smaller than yesterday at this time.

```
Option Explicit
dim strTest, re, matches, myDatePart, myTimePart, logDate

' teststring
strTest = "08-Nov-13  14:10:56.3496 ( -1 7020 10244) scpeng.exe:CServer.cpp,...."

Set re = new regexp

' This pattern extracts two part, the date as (dd-www-dd) and the time as (hh:mm:ss)
re.pattern = "(\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{2}) +(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})"
Set matches = re.Execute(strTest)

' Get the first and second submatch to define the date and time
myDatePart = matches(0).submatches(0)
myTimePart = matches(0).submatches(1)

' datevalue and timevalue automatically tranforms to Date type
logDate = datevalue(myDatePart) + timevalue(myTimePart)

' See if the date is smaller than yesterday exactly this time
msgbox (logDate < (DateAdd("d", -1, now))) ' Returns True, because 08 Nov is earlier than yesterday.
```